# What is the difference between F5AL250V and F5L250V fuses?

Tags: identification, fuses

In the glass fuses' code **F** is for fast blown the second number is the current, but I do not know what is the difference between **L** an **AL** (if there is any).

Could someone explain this.

Comment: Please link to both data sheets.

Comment: @Andyaka Unfortunately, I haven't any datasheet otherwise it would have been enough to read them to find the answer.

Comment: Are you therefore suspecting that someone does have these data sheets then?

Comment: @Andyaka It's enough to find someone that has experience with the fuse code letters. The labeling is pretty standard for the glass fuses.

Comment: Who makes them then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are the same 5A 250V fast acting low breaking capacity fuses (just one omits the A of ampere)

The glass cartridge fuse code is structured in this way

```
|Acting Speed| |Current rating| |Breaking capacity| |Voltage rating|
```

or

```
|Package size code| |Acting Speed| |Current rating| |Breaking capacity| |Voltage rating|
```

## Acting speed

The time it takes for the fuse to open when a fault current occurs. 
It code could be:

**FF** - Very Fast Acting (Flink Flink)

**F** - Fast Acting (Flink)

**M** - Medium Acting (Mitteltrage)

**T** - Slow Acting (Trage)

**TT** - Very Slow Acting (Trage Trage)

## Fuse Breaking Capacity

It is the current that a fuse is able to interrupt without being destroyed or causing an electric arc with unacceptable duration. The capacity of a fuse to operate between the lowest and the Rated Breaking Current code could be:

**H** - High Breaking Capacity

**L** - Low Breaking Capacity

Answer (score 0):

They are apparently a different size 3/16 vs 4/16 diameter and 3/4 vs l inch length.

I base this on having just bought 5 amp which didn't fit a 5al socket.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/347109)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/347109)

Comment: @DanieleTampieri The expression "how do I know" is NOT asking a new question. It is an idiomtic way of saying "I know thi because ... "

Comment: @DavideAndrea  The expression "how do I know" is NOT asking a new question. It is an idiomtic way of saying "I know thi because ... "

Comment: @Russell McMahon Yes, I understand that  "how do I know" is NOT asking a new question.. That is unrelated to my evaluation that Harold's post does not answer OP's question.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, thank you for pointing it out. However Harold's post in nevertheless not an answer.